# How patch multiple method of same object

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-mock

I want to patch multiples method of same object. I am trying
`@patch.multiple('pdb.Pdb', do_continue=DEFAULT, do_step=DEFAULT, do_exit=DEFAULT)` it throws error during running Test
`NameError: name 'DEFAULT' is not defined`

Comment: Define `DEFAULT` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unittest.mock.DEFAULT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.DEFAULT) needs to be imported first. This will run without error:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest.mock import DEFAULT

patch.multiple('pdb.Pdb', do_continue=DEFAULT, do_step=DEFAULT, do_exit=DEFAULT)
```

Comment: btw I found that silly mistake later but thanks for the answer.